# If using a Timer control do you need to use Async Task?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, asynchronous, timer

I have a Windows form GUI that polls a database server every X minutes. If it finds data it posts the data to an HTTP API. Since I am using a Timer to accomplish the polling do I still need to make use of asynchronous code such as this when calling the API?

```
Task.Run(async () =>
{
  // Call HTTP code here
}).Wait();
```

I would like the GUI to remain responsive and not lock up.

I am new to asynchronous development in .NET and still not sure how to implement it properly.

Comment: That code *isn't* asynchronous *because you're synchronously waiting on it.  If you want to know if the code will work by synchronously doing the work in a timer *then try it and find out*.  You'll have your answer either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Since I am using a Timer to accomplish the polling do I still need to make use of asynchronous code such as this when calling the API?

If you're using [`System.Threading.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) then you dont **have to** use an async api to keep your GUI responsive as these will invoke the delegate passed to them on a `ThreadPool` thread. Specifically in your example, you're mistakenly using `Wait` which waits synchronously on the new thread you're creating, which makes no sense.

If the only thing your delegate is doing is IO bound calls, such as a HTTP request or an async database call (for example, EF exposes async endpoints) then you dont need the extra thread to keep you UI responsive.

Here's an example using [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.delay(v=vs.110).aspx) (which internally uses a timer) which is purely async:

```
public async Task PoolAndWaitAsync(int timeToWait)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    while (true)
    { 
        // Query database
        var data = await MyDatabase.QueryAsync(..);

        if (data != null)
        { 
             var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(..);
        }

        await Task.Delay(timeToWait);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you make your HTTP Code asynchronous.  Provided you use an async API within that event handler, it should be fine to not wrap in a separate `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Task` object iteself performs in async operations. Servy is right. You have to remove the `.Wait()`.

But as long as you want to populate some controls within your async method, you have to be sure to be thread safe.

Cheers, Martin